# object instantiation syntax, ClassName() vs new ClassName()

Tags: dart

Is there a difference between instantiating objects in these two ways?

```
void main() {
  var example = new ClassName()
}
```

vs

```
void main() {
  var example = ClassName()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Dart 2.0 `new` is optional, so they are equivalent.
If the context requires `const` and `new` or `const` are omitted, then `const` is used automatically instead of `new`
(except for parameter default values because there the requirement for `const` might be dropped eventually)